# Do pixel densities affect positioning of elements across various devices?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm building a custom slideshow and I want my slide controls to always be at a certain position on the bottom of the window. To accomplish this I'm using jQuery and setting the top property of the div containing the controls to the `window height - 50px`.

My question is, if the site is viewed on a device with a high pixel density does this approach still work? I have nothing to test on and appreciate any feedback. In my mind I think that if a device has a high pixel density `50px` will only move it slightly, but I'm hoping I am wrong.

Comment: Yes it will work. It's still 50 pixels. If you are referring to a "retina display" from apple, it will be converted to 100 pixels internally

Comment: Thanks for giving me some peace of mind.

Comment: Well, I've posted that comment as an answer with some added details. If that helps, cast an upvote if you can. If it answers your question, click the check mark underneath the voting arrows.

Comment: As an aside: why use JQuery when CSS will do... `.slide-controls{position:fixed;bottom:50px;}`

Answer (score 2):

CSS **`px`** units **are not pixels**.

This includes their use in jQuery. **`px`** units do not correspond directly to physical pixels on the display.

w3.org has [a page that explains `px` and other CSS units](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html):

> The **px** unit is the magic unit of CSS. It is not related to the current font and also not related to the absolute units. The **px** unit is defined to be small but visible, and such that a horizontal 1px wide line can be displayed with sharp edges (no anti-aliasing). What is sharp, small and visible depends on the device and the way it is used: do you hold it close to your eyes, like a mobile phone, at arms length, like a computer monitor, or somewhere in between, like a book? The **px** is thus not defined as a constant length, but as something that depends on the type of device and its typical use.
>
> To get an idea of the appearance of a **px**, imagine a CRT computer monitor from the 1990s: the smallest dot it can display measures about 1/100th of an inch (0.25mm) or a little more. The **px** unit got its name from those screen pixels.
>
> Nowadays there are devices that could in principle display smaller sharp dots (although you might need a magnifier to see them). But documents from the last century that used **px** in CSS still look the same, no matter what the device. Printers, especially, can display sharp lines with much smaller details than 1px, but even on printers, a 1px line looks very much the same as it would look on a computer monitor. Devices change, but the **px** always has the same visual appearance.

Another way to think about this is that [CSS px is an Angular Measurement](http://inamidst.com/stuff/notes/csspx):

> “Pixel units are relative to the resolution of the viewing device, i.e., most often a computer display. If the pixel density of the output device is very different from that of a typical computer display, the user agent should rescale pixel values. It is recommended that the *reference pixel* be the visual angle of one pixel on a device with a pixel density of 96dpi and a distance from the reader of an arm's length. For a nominal arm's length of 28 inches, the visual angle is therefore about 0.0213 degrees.”

So your `-50px` should appear visually to be approximately the same size on any device. The actual number of pixels that corresponds to will depend on the device's pixel density, how far the device is intended to be from the user's eyes, and also user customization.

Comment: Huh? I tested this. I took a printscreen of a 50px line on a 72 ppi and a 96 ppi screen. I then measured the size in Paint.NET and they both measured as 50 px.

Comment: Yeah, this is hinted at by the W3's comment "The px unit is defined to be small but visible, and such that a horizontal 1px wide line can be displayed with sharp edges (no anti-aliasing)." This suggests that the browser may do a retina-style pixel doubling but should avoid fractional scaling. One exception is when the user has set a browser zoom factor. Then of course you'll see your 50px turn into a larger number of physical pixels.

Answer (score 0):

The pixel density can affect the appearance, but not the layout.  Pixel density is overall a very, very minor aspect and is handled by video drivers and the operating system rather than your CSS directly.  It's begun common for companies to advertise pixel densities as a way of differentiating their product, but this doesn't mean its a new thing.

All PCs, laptops, tables, phones, and TVs with the same resolution but different screen dimensions (even just different aspect ratios) have different pixel densities.  While we do have to consider different resolutions, we do not have to consider pixel density.

While not exclusively a pixel-density concern font choice may one of the styling aspects that could be affected.  A font that a finely tuned to render well on a given screen (as well as browser, and operating system) potentially won't look as good on others.  There are many factors other than just pixel density at play here, such as sub-pixel rendering.

The bottom line is the same as it has been for quite a while.  Design your content; test it thoroughly on diverse devices (if possible) and you should be fine.